# Main thread vs websocket thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, python-asyncio

I can't find how to structure my code, despite having looked at all the questions on asyncio, threading, queues, process, coroutine, etc... Here
is a toy example that reflects my problem.

The main thread calls :

```
... 
myClass = MyClass()
answer = myClass.sendAndGetAnswer("Hello how are you ?") 
print(answer) # Should print the answer recieved over webSocket, 
              # for eg "I'm doing well" 
...
```

I cannot touch the code above, my task is to implement `MyClass` so that `myClass.sendAndGetAnswer(msg)` sends a message over the already opened websocket and returns the answer. It is thus blocking the main thread as long as it does not have the answer. Also `sendAndGetAnswer(msg)` will be called many times and so I need the websocket connection to stay open between `sendAndGetAnswer(msg)` calls.

From what I understand, `websocket` uses `asyncio` which would block anything else to happen if I don't use it in a parallel thread (because of the `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()` )

So I would do :

```
class MyClass()

   def __init__(self):
      loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
      t = Thread(target=self.start_loop, args=(loop,))
      t.start()

   def start_loop(self, loop):
      asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
      loop.run_until_complete(websockets.serve(self.serverHandler, '127.0.0.1', 9999))
      loop.run_forever()

   async def serverHandler(websocket, path):
       ... ?

   def sendAndGetAnswer(self, msg):
       # Send the message & get the answer
       ... ?
       return answer
```

So I could attempt something along those lines :

```
class MyClass()

   def __init__(self):

       self.lastMsg = None

       loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
       t = Thread(target=self.start_loop, args=(loop,))
       t.start()

   def start_loop(self, loop):
       asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
       loop.run_until_complete(websockets.serve(self.serverHandler, '127.0.0.1', 9999))
       loop.run_forever()

   async def serverHandler(websocket, path):
       self.ws = websocket
       async for message in websocket:
           self.lastMsg = message

   def sendAndGetAnswer(self, msg):
       # Send the message & get the answer
       self.ws.send(msg)
       while self.lastMsg != None
          pass
       return self.lastMsg
```

But this surely is not the solution. Could you help me formulate the code for MyClass ?

Thanks